# How can I use child_process.spawn to pause a media player?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin

I'm trying to [control](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html) [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) with a node.js program using child_process.spawn.

I am having trouble resuming the playback after I paused it. For some reason, an `exit` event is sent even though mplayer hasn't finished playing.

What am I doing wrong?

The following code works fine (I can hear the music play) until the second pause command.

```
var spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawn;
var mplayer;
var file = '/Users/snorpey/Music/Blink-182/Untitled/01 Feeling This.m4a';

mplayer = spawn( 'mplayer', [ file ] );
mplayer.on( 'exit', function(){ console.log( 'EXIT.' ); } );

setTimeout( pause, 5000 );
setTimeout( pause, 9000 );

function pause()
{
    console.log( 'PAUSE', mplayer.stdin );
    mplayer.stdin.write( 'p\n' );
}
```

The first output for mplayer.stdin looks like this:

```
{ _handle: 
   { writeQueueSize: 0,
     owner: [Circular],
     onread: [Function: onread] },
  _pendingWriteReqs: 0,
  _flags: 0,
  _connectQueueSize: 0,
  destroyed: false,
  errorEmitted: false,
  bytesRead: 0,
  _bytesDispatched: 0,
  allowHalfOpen: undefined,
  writable: true,
  readable: false }
```

The second one like this:

```
{ _handle: null,
  _pendingWriteReqs: 0,
  _flags: 0,
  _connectQueueSize: 0,
  destroyed: true,
  errorEmitted: false,
  bytesRead: 0,
  _bytesDispatched: 2,
  allowHalfOpen: undefined,
  writable: false,
  readable: false,
  _connecting: false,
  _connectQueue: null,
  _idleNext: null,
  _idlePrev: null,
  _idleTimeout: -1 }
```

I get the following error:

```
events.js:66
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: This socket is closed.
    at Socket._write (net.js:517:19)
    at Socket.write (net.js:509:15)
    at Object.pause [as _onTimeout] (/Users/snorpey/Sites/Development/mplayer/pause.js:14:16)
    at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without attempting to test or debug a few thoughts come to mind:

Use mplayer's slave mode.  You do this by giving it the `-slave` flag at startup.  See http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt for more info.

Setup code to show what mplayers wants to tell you.  Might be more meaningful than watching the socket status.

```
var spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawn;
var mplayer;
var file = '/Users/snorpey/Music/Blink-182/Untitled/01 Feeling This.m4a';

mplayer = spawn( 'mplayer', [ '-slave', file ] );
mplayer.on( 'exit', function () { console.log( 'EXIT.' ); } );

// obviously you'll want something smarter than just logging...
mplayer.stdout.on('data', function (data) { console.log('mplayer stdout: ' + data); });
mplayer.stderr.on('data', function (data) { console.log('mplayer stderr: ' + data); });

setTimeout( pause, 5000 );
setTimeout( pause, 9000 );

function pause() {
    console.log( 'PAUSE' );
    mplayer.stdin.write( 'pausing\n' );
}
```

Comment: This seems to fix it. I don't get the error when using the ```-slave``` flag. Awesome. Thank you!